# Infinite loop at file reader in c

Tags: c, logging

I tried to make a code that calculates the average time of execution from another process (that writes how many cores used and time took to it to finish). The thing is that it is getting stuck in the linecounter() function.

Here is a sample log.txt that I will be reading:

```
1 11.3484
1 10.8089
1 10.7293
```

And here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct result{
  double *runtime;
  int *size;
}R1;

int linecounter(FILE *fileptr)
{
  int count_lines=0;
  char chr=getc(fileptr);
  while (chr != EOF)
  {
    printf("Inside the linecounter function()\n");
    //Count whenever new line is encountered
    if (chr == '\n') //works because I dont have any N in my txt, take care
    {
      count_lines++;
    }
    //take next character from file.
    chr = getc(fileptr);
  }
  return count_lines;
}

int main()
{
  FILE *f;
  f=fopen("log.txt","r");
  if(f == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error! opening the file");   
    exit(1);             
  }
  printf("Counting lines\n");
  int n=linecounter(f);

  R1.runtime=malloc(n*sizeof(double));
  R1.size=malloc(n*sizeof(int));

  int j=1,k=0;
  printf("Reading file\n"); 
  j=fscanf(f,"%d %6.4f",&R1.size[k],&R1.runtime[k]); //First number of cores, then runtime
  k++;
  while(j!=EOF)
  {
    j=fscanf(f,"%d %6.4f",&R1.size[k],&R1.runtime[k]); //First number of cores, then runtime
    k++;
  }

  int AvgRuntime=0,i=0;

  if(R1.size[i]==1)
  {
    while(R1.size[i]==1) //for 1 core
    {
      AvgRuntime+=R1.runtime[i];
      i++;
    }
  }
  
  AvgRuntime=AvgRuntime/i;
  printf("Avg Runtime: %6.4f",AvgRuntime);
  int prev_i=i;
  AvgRuntime=0;
  if(R1.size[i]==2)
  {
    while(R1.size[i]==2) //for 2 core
    {
      AvgRuntime+=R1.runtime[i];
      i++;
    }
  }
  
  AvgRuntime=AvgRuntime/(i-prev_i);
  printf("Avg Runtime: %6.4f",AvgRuntime);
  prev_i=i;
  AvgRuntime=0;
  if(R1.size[i]==4)
  {
    while(R1.size[i]==4) //for 4 core
    {
      AvgRuntime+=R1.runtime[i];
      i++;
    }
  }
  
  AvgRuntime=AvgRuntime/(i-prev_i);
  printf("Avg Runtime: %6.4f",AvgRuntime);
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

It is pretty simple, I have 3 options, to use 1 2 or 4 cores, so I calculate the average for each case and overwrite it for the next one. The problems come when trying to get how many lines were written in the file.

By adding a printf() in the linecounter function, I noticed that it never achieves the end of file. Has it some kind of solution?

Comment: `j=!EOF` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: "I started adding printf everywhere to understand the problem but they are not even being printed" -- The stream `stdout` is normally line-buffered when connected to a terminal/console. Therefore, if you want to see the diagnostic output immediately, you must either (1) add a newline character at the end of the output, or (2) add a `fflush( stdout );` after the output, or (3) print to `stderr` instead of `stdout` (`stderr` is normally not buffered). In order to print to `stderr`, you will have to use the function `fprintf` instead of `printf`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes, I just noticed that a minute ago and edited all the question. Sorry :(

Comment: @user253751 as far as I understand, j=fscanf() returns a positive value, and if it fails to get the data, it will return EOF, as I allocate it in j, and compare j to EOF, if j==EOF it will finish the while loop

Comment: You do not compare `j` with `EOF`. You assign the value `!EOF` to `j`. As `EOF!=0`, `!EOF` evaluates to `0`. What you do is same as `while (j=0)` which again is same as `while (false)`. What you want to do is `j != EOF`. `!=` is a compound operator, `=!` is an assignment operator followed by a unary logical negation.

Comment: Besides that, `j` is not initialized when you reach that loop for the first time and `fscanf` could also return `0` or `1` if it is not able to convert both values. Your compiler should tell you about using `j` without assigning a value first. If not, you should enable more warnings. You could rewrite that condition as `while (fscanf( ...) == 2){ k++; }`

Comment: @Gerhardh cheeses, I did not noticed that I wrote =!. Eventhough, my problem is in the function linecounter(). I update the corrected code, thanks

Comment: I noticed that the problem is in the file, it does not have an EOF apparently, as I am trying printing each time that I am in the linecounter() while loop and it is not even stopping the print.

Comment: Return type of `getc` is `int`, not `char`. Your condition still does not account for other possible return values of `fscanf`.  Why do you use that condition if you already know the number of lines to read? Finally, after counting the lines in the file, you need to rewind if you want to read those lines afterward.

Comment: When I run your code, I get division by zero error. I am not stuck in `lineconter`. Maybe your `char` is unsigned and cannot hold `EOF`.

Comment: `getc` returns an `int`, change type of `chr`. `scanf` returns 0 if nothing has been converted. Change accordingly.

Comment: I wonder what this even means: *problem is in the file, it does not have an EOF apparently* Every file has an end. `EOF` is not a specific content of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your code.

`getc` returns an `int`, not a `char`. If your `char` is unsigned by default, it is not able to hold value `EOF` and your comparison `chr != EOF` will never be true.

After you have counted the lines in the file, the file pointer is at the end of the file. You cannot read any further value from it. You must rewind it before you can scan the content.

Your format specifier `%6.4f` is invalid for `scanf`. You cannot specify precision. You can only do that when you print values.

Your format specifier `%f` expects a `float*` as argument but you provide `double*`. For `double` use `%lf`. You can print `floats` using `%f` but you must use `%lf` for `scanf`.

You print your calculated average using `%6.4f` but `AvgRuntime` is of type `int`.
This also means that the calculation of the average is done using integer division. There will not be any decimals as the result is chopped off.
Make `AvgRuntime` a `double instead.

Your compiler should tell you quite a few of these problems.
If you did not get warnings, you should increase warning level significantly.
If you did get these warnings, what made you just ignore all of them?

You also have logical errors.
Your averaging only works if the entries in the log file are sorted. You must read all lines for core 1 first, then all lines for core 2 and then for core 4. If the file is not sorted, your calculations will fail.

Also, if you do not have entries for a core, you will do a division by zero as you don't check value of `i` vs. `prev_i`.

Finally, `printf` to `stdout` is normally line buffered. Output is not printed unless a `\n` is reached. You should add a `\n` at the end of your `printf` lines when you print the averages.

A fixed version (except the problems with calculating averages) could look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct result{
  double *runtime;
  int *size;
}R1;

int linecounter(FILE *fileptr)
{
  int count_lines=0;
  int chr=getc(fileptr);
  while (chr != EOF)
  {
//    printf("Inside the linecounter function()\n");
    //Count whenever new line is encountered
    if (chr == '\n') //works because I dont have any N in my txt, take care
    {
      count_lines++;
    }
    //take next character from file.
    chr = getc(fileptr);
  }
  rewind (fileptr);
  return count_lines;
}

int main()
{
  FILE *f;
  f=fopen("log.txt","r");
  if(f == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error! opening the file");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("Counting lines\n");
  int n=linecounter(f);

  R1.runtime=malloc(n*sizeof(double));
  R1.size=malloc(n*sizeof(int));

  int j=1,k=0;
  printf("Reading file\n");
  j=fscanf(f,"%d %lf",&R1.size[k],&R1.runtime[k]); //First number of cores, then runtime
  k++;
  while(j==2)
  {
    j=fscanf(f,"%d %lf",&R1.size[k],&R1.runtime[k]); //First number of cores, then runtime
    k++;
  }

  int i=0;
  double AvgRuntime=0.0;
  if(R1.size[i]==1)
  {
    while(R1.size[i]==1) //for 1 core
    {
      AvgRuntime+=R1.runtime[i];
      i++;
    }
  }
  AvgRuntime=AvgRuntime/i;
  printf("Avg Runtime: %6.4f\n",AvgRuntime);

  int prev_i=i;
  AvgRuntime=0.0;
  if(R1.size[i]==2)
  {
    while(R1.size[i]==2) //for 2 core
    {
      AvgRuntime+=R1.runtime[i];
      i++;
    }
  }
  AvgRuntime=AvgRuntime/(i-prev_i);
  printf("Avg Runtime: %6.4f\n",AvgRuntime);

  prev_i=i;
  AvgRuntime=0;
  if(R1.size[i]==4)
  {
    while(R1.size[i]==4) //for 4 core
    {
      AvgRuntime+=R1.runtime[i];
      i++;
    }
  }
  AvgRuntime=AvgRuntime/(i-prev_i);
  printf("Avg Runtime: %6.4f\n",AvgRuntime);

  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

Output with your file:

```
Counting lines
Reading file
Avg Runtime: 10.9622
Avg Runtime:   -nan
Avg Runtime:   -nan
```

Comment: Thanks too much. I did not got any of the warnings, and I was wondering why, I have just been told that I have to tell linux the level of warnings, and I have modified the bash script that runs the code to have Wall Wextra and Pedantic. Thanks for everything, and sorry for bothering you with this noob mistakes :).

Comment: I am uploading the final version just in case anyone faces this problem. Thanks!!

Comment: You should get some of the warnings even if you call `gcc` without any extra option. Your updated code still uses wrong condition `while(j!=EOF)`. If you fail to read both numbers from a line, `fscanf` will return `1` or `0` and might be stuck forever.

Comment: Oh okay, I am correcting that rn

Comment: @EnzoBasile Example of code with and without extra warnings enabled: https://godbolt.org/z/Pfs4593xh You pretty much always want the extra warnings;. Every logic mistake the compiler can catch for you means less debugging.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks! I have updated my bash script to run it and added more levels of warnings.